# configure flexigrid helper, and customize variable $colModel

Tags: codeigniter, flexigrid

I try to start Flexigrid into Codeigniter.

I download demo files from here
 http://gembelzillonmendonk.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/flexigrid-and-codeigniter-with-advanced-searching-with-example/

but i wrong to set up something:

Instruction from site:

- extract .rar to CI folder**
- open your controller (ie: CI_Folder\system\application\controllers\flexigrid.php)**
- configure flexigrid helper, and customize variable $colModel, example:**

  code example

What I did:

- I installed correctly CodeIgniter (*copy and paste inside htdocs - xampp*)
- I created a database called 'country' and import sql file inside demo.
- I copied correctly files an folders from demo files to my CI folder (*called grocery-crud-demo*).

But when I type on firefox http://localhost/grocery-crud-demo/index.php/flexigrid/index I have this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\grocery-crud-demo\application\controllers\flexigrid.php on line 2
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Controller' not found

Filename: controllers/flexigrid.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:
```

I read instruction also from here: http://roadmyapps.toile-libre.org/index.php/flexigrid/example
but I don't understand which code exactly I must have into **flexigrid.php**

I don't understand how configure flexigrid helper, and customize variable $colModel.

### I need exact code into files. Have you idea?

---

**I find CodeIgniter 1.7.3 -- I repeat steps -- new error:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Ajax_model::$db

Filename: models/ajax_model.php

Line Number: 34

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\grocery-crud-demo\system\application\models\ajax_model.php on line 34
```

Code of ajax_model.php is this: http://pastebin.com/P3KawC7S

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using newer version of CI than one on tutorial.
As I can see tutorial is written for 1.7.2 version.

Try to change

```
class Someclass extends Controller
{
  public function someclass()
  {
  }
  public function index()
  {
    //etc, etc
  }
}
```

with

```
class Someclass extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct()
    {
    }
  }
  public function index()
  {
    //etc, etc
  }
}
```

Also, for models too. Like

```
public function Ajax_model()
{
    parent::Model();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

should be

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

Try that way.
Spot those differences. Those should change in every controller and model respectivelly. Follow [this link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) for upgrading your app.
If fail again, see the CodeIgniter documentation about upgrading versions.

Comment: I find CodeIgniter 1.7.3...I repeat steps and now I have a new error, seems to be easy:  `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\grocery-crud-demo\system\application\models\ajax_model.php on line 34` . Code inside ajax_model.php is this: http://pastebin.com/P3KawC7S. What must edit?

Comment: I try your solutions but doesn't work. I try also last version of CI (3.x) but when i enter http://localhost/grocery-crud-demo/index.php/flexigrid/index it give me 404 error, how is possible?

Comment: If your main goal is to implement grocery-crud, just go to their website and follow instruction for integration. In that case you should have CI 2.1 at least.